# Image sending through socket C++ server and C# client

Tags: c#, c++, image, sockets

I'm developing a windows store application, using C#. I would like to make TCP connection to receive images (for now) from a desktop server. the server is in C++ .

I have a client C++ to test the function and it is working perfectly. Now what i want is a similar client but in C# . I tried converting it but no luck,  i tried to use the same logic but i had tons of errors and deleted everything.

Help is appreciated,thanks.

C++ Server

```
int size = 8192;     //image size
char* bufferCMP;
bufferCMP = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* size);
FILE *p_file;
p_file = fopen("C:\\Program Files\\img1.png", "rb");
fread(bufferCMP, 1, size, p_file);
fclose(p_file);


int chunkcount = size / DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
int lastchunksize = size - (chunkcount * DEFAULT_BUFLEN);
int fileoffset = 0;

printf("Sending actual Chunk");
while (chunkcount > 0)
{
    iResult = send(ClientSocket, bufferCMP + (fileoffset * DEFAULT_BUFLEN), DEFAULT_BUFLEN, 0);
    fileoffset++;
    chunkcount--;

    if (iResult != DEFAULT_BUFLEN)
    {
        printf("Sending Buffer size <> Default buffer length  ::: %d\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Sending Buffer size = %d \n", iResult, fileoffset);
    }
}

printf("Sending last Chunk", lastchunksize);
iResult = send(ClientSocket, bufferCMP + (fileoffset * DEFAULT_BUFLEN), lastchunksize, 0);
```

`

C++ Client  (to be converted into C#)

```
int size = 8192;


int FileCounter = 0;
bool flg = true;
char * fileComplete;
char * filesizeBuffer;

FILE *temp;

int receiveBuffer = 0;
int desiredRecBuffer = size;
//int desiredRecBuffer = DEFAULT_BUFLEN ; 
fileComplete = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* size);

while (desiredRecBuffer > 0)
{
    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, fileComplete + receiveBuffer, desiredRecBuffer, 0);
    //iResult = recv( ClientSocket, fileComplete + receiveBuffer , fileSize , 0 );

    if (iResult < 1)
    {
        printf("Reveive Buffer Error  %d \n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        receiveBuffer += iResult;
        desiredRecBuffer = size - receiveBuffer;
        printf("Reveived Data size :  %d \n", desiredRecBuffer);

    }
}

FILE *File = fopen("C:\\Users\\amirk_000\\Pictures\\img1b.png", "wb");
fwrite(fileComplete, 1, size, File);
//flg = true;
free(fileComplete);
fclose(File);
```

Comment: You'er not using the return value of recv consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full example of C# client socket is available [at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Modify the given `SocketSendReceive` method to write the received buffer (`bytesReceived` array) to a file stream.

Something like the following should do it:

```
    using (var file = File.OpenWrite("myimage.png"))
    {
        do
        {
            bytes = s.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0);
            file.Write(bytesReceived, 0, bytes);
        }
        while (bytes > 0);
    }
```